# Omit page header on last page of Access report?

Tags: ms-access, report

How do I remove the header on the last page of Access report?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a Group to your report, grouping on the expression `=True`. That will create a group that includes all records in the report.

Give that group a Group Header, then move the column heading labels from the Page Header to the Group Header. In the Properties for the Group Header, set `Repeat Section` to `Yes` so the column headings appear on each page of the group.

When the report prints the Report Footer (with the totals) it has moved past the end of the group (i.e., past the last record in the report) so the column headings should not appear.