# Access 2010 report issue: Repeating field(s) at the top of a new page

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a text field that may overflow to another page. I would like to have another field reprint when the text field overflows, so there is more identifying info on the subsequent pages.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Group Header and set its `Repeat Section` property to `Yes` so it repeats at the top of a new page. See my answer to a sort-of-related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126134/2144390) for more details.